# useReducer simplification

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Can someone explain me the useReducer hook in extremely simplified form, I've tried watching many tutorials and read some blogs but somehow didn't understand exactly how is it working and where should I use it?

Comment: I would recommend reading the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) and looking at the example they provide.